# Using try_cast in snowflake to deal with very long numbers

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using **try_cast** in snowflake to convert any long values in sql to NULL.

Here is my code:

When I try running the above code, I'm getting the error as below:

I'm flattening a JSON array and using try_cast to make any large values to NULL because I was getting an error **Failed to cast variant value {numberLong: -8301085358432}**

```
SELECT try_cast(item.value:price) as item_price,
       try_cast(item.value:total_price_bill) as items_total_price
FROM table, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => products) item
```

**Error:**

> SQL compilation error error at line 1 at position ')'.

I don't understand where I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong syntax for try_cast. according to [snowflake documentations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_cast.html) the syntax  is :

```
TRY_CAST( <source_string_expr> AS <target_data_type> )
```

and also note:

1. Only works for string expressions.
2. target_data_type must be one of the following:

   - VARCHAR (or any of its synonyms)
   - NUMBER (or any of its synonyms)
   - DOUBLE
   - BOOLEAN
   - DATE
   - TIME
   - TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP_LTZ, TIMESTAMP_NTZ, or TIMESTAMP_TZ

so for example you have to have something like this if `item.value:price`  is string:

```
select try_cast(item.value:price as NUMBER) as item_price,
....
```